# GL_REPEAT not working for video.mp4 but OK for image.png

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, mp4

GL_REPEAT is working OK for an image using GL_TEXTURE_2D, but not for an mp4 using GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES. I need this in order to create an infinite type scroll effect to shift pixels and export the changes.

In the fragment shader, the infinite horizontal scroll effect can be achieved by:

```
uniform float scroll;
void main() {
    vec2 coord = vec2(v_TexCoordinate.x + scroll, v_TexCoordinate.y);
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, coord);
}
```

In my GlSurface, my geometry and initial gl setup is defined below:

```
private static final float squareVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, 1.0f,    // top left
    -1.0f, -1.0f,   // bottom left
    1.0f, -1.0f,    // bottom right
    1.0f, 1.0f      // top right
};

private static final float textureVertices[] = {                // in counterclockwise order:
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f
};

private void glSetup() {
    final String vertexShader = Utils.readTextFileFromRawResource(mMainActivity,
            R.raw.media_vertex_shader);
    String fragmentShader = null;

    if (isVideo) {
        fragmentShader = Utils.readTextFileFromRawResource(mMainActivity,
                R.raw.media_fragment_shader_video);
    } else {
        fragmentShader = Utils.readTextFileFromRawResource(mMainActivity,
                R.raw.media_fragment_shader_image);
    }

    final int vertexShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShader);
    final int fragmentShaderHandle = ShaderHelper.compileShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShader);

    int[] textures = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    mTextureId = textures[0];

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(mTextureUniformHandle, 0);

    if (isVideo) {
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureId);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);

        mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(mTextureId);
        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(mSurfaceTexture);
        mSurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this);
    } else {                        //image
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    }

    mScrollHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "scroll");

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
}
```

And onDrawFame():

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (isVideo) {
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureId);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        Log.d(TAG, GLES20.glGetError());
    } else {
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, mImage, 0);
    }
}

@Override  //only called for video
synchronized public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface) {
    mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
    mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(stMatrix);;
}
```

I see an GL_INVALID_ENUM when logging GLES20.glGetError()

What I have tried doing:

1. Resizing the video using ffmpeg to POT (power-of-two, 2048 x 1024)
2. Using GLES30/GLES31/GLES32 for all binding, parameter, etc. calls
3. Changing textureVertices and squareVertices to > 1.0f
4. Printing the width/height of texture using GL31.glGetTexLevelParameteriv() which prints out 0 for both width&height for a video but proper dimensions for an image

Unsure if GL_Repeat should work on target GL_Texture_External_OES for an mp4 file. It sounds like it should be repeatable, according to the [OpenGl Notes Section](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml)

Any other suggestions to try are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported. See specification "Issue 2":

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt

Specifically:

> 2. Should the wrap mode of an external texture be allowed to be anything other than CLAMP_TO_EDGE?
>
>    ```
>    RESOLVED: no
>    ```